# Tooltip function and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using following jQuery to style my tooltips

```
  $(function() {

        // select all desired input fields and attach tooltips to them
      $("#tooltips :input").tooltip({

      // place tooltip on the right edge
      position: "center left",

      // a little tweaking of the position
      offset: [-2, 10],

      // use the built-in fadeIn/fadeOut effect
      effect: "fade",

      });
    });
```

and my CSS is

```
#myform {
    height: auto;
  }
  #tooltip{
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #fff !important;
  border: 1px solid !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #bbb #bbb #a8a8a8;
  padding: 16px;
  z-index: 2000 !important;
  width: 255px;
  line-height: 17px;
  top: 48px;
  margin-left:-16px !important;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #7d7d7d;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.218s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.218s;
  -o-transition: all 0.218s;
  transition: all 0.218s;
  }
#tooltip:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        border: 3px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9);
        border-color: transparent white;
        border-width: 8px 0 8px 7px;
        top: 40%;
        right: -6px;
}

#tooltip:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        border: 2px solid #333;
        border-color: transparent #000;
        border-width: 8px 0 8px 6px;
        top: 40%;
        right: -6px;
}
```

I'd like to change the CSS name to anything else rather than tooltip, but when i change my CSS name the tooltip doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try bootstrap tooltip. its easy to use 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Comment: you can use any name instead of #tooltips eg #mytooltips but the element name should be the same

Answer (score 0):

update the jQuery selector accordingly. For ex if want to name it `anyRandomName` then

selector should be

```
$("#anyRandomName:input").tooltip({
   //...
});
```

Also make sure the element on which you want to show tootip have id as `anyRandomName`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to ask, but if you want to replace 'tooltip' with any other string like 'test' in CSS then you will have to replace same string inside `$('#tooltip :input')` by same name `$('#test :input')`.

Comment: I'm using tooltip for input fields based on following link http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/form.html
it just work with .tooltip css not anything else

Comment: I got your point. You need to go through jquery.tools.min.js and search for keyword tipClass:"tooltip" and change tipClass:"tooltip" to tipClass:"test" i.e. place name of your class instead of "test".